# How to unregister style using TStyleManager::UnRegisterStyle()

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl-styles, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I want to unregister a specific style using this code:

```
void __fastcall TfrmMain::btnUnregStyleClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    TCustomStyleServices *MyStyle;

    // Get wanted style
    MyStyle = TStyleManager::Style["Emerald"];   // this will return a TCustomStyleServices obj

    if (MyStyle != NULL)
    {
        // Remove it
        TStyleManager::UnRegisterStyle(MyStyle);   // This will set default Windows style (no style)
    }
}
```

It works. The style seems to be unregistered, and the GUI switches automatically to the default Windows style.

But when program shuts down, I get this error:

> Project Project.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message
>   'access violation at 0x5005fd50: read of address 0xffffffd0'.

Here is the Call stack:

```
:5005fd50 rtl250.@System@TObject@InheritsFrom$qqrp17System@TMetaClass + 0x8
:50d12a8d vcl250.@Vcl@Styles@TStyleEngine@Notification$qqr54Vcl@Themes@TCustomStyleEngine@TStyleEngineNotificationpv + 0x1d
:00e5a612 vclwinx250.@Vcl@Winxctrls@TSearchBox@$bcdtr$qqrv + 0x1e
:0041fa0f __cleanup + 0x1F
:0041fb92 ; __wstartup
```

[Update: this crash is fixed if I remove TeeChart from my form. But `UnRegisterStyle()` still won't work]

---

If after `UnRegisterStyle()` I call:

```
TStyleManager::LoadFromFile(usStylePath);
TStyleManager::SetStyle("Emerald");
```

it will tell me that the "emerald style is already registered".

So, obviously `UnRegisterStyle()` fails.

Getting the "styles" list via `TStyleManager::StyleNames()` shows that the list remains unchanged after `UnRegisterStyle()`.

Embarcadero has no help on this function. Should I call something else, additionally to `UnRegisterStyle()`?

Comment: Do you use standard components for building your GUI? Does this problem occur on "blank" project?

Comment: oh... the only one that is not "standard" (from Embarcadero) is TeeChart. I will get rid of it.

Comment: the crash DOES NOT appear after I remove the TeeChart control and all references to it (#include). However, the UnRegisterStyle still doesn't work.

Comment: now the "UnRegisterStyle  does not unregister" bug can be reproduced with an empty form and 2 buttons (see code above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer has been updated! Again.**

Well, I am not very experienced user of `VCL`'s styles but I will try to explain what to do to avoid your problem. Before you will read further I should tell you: *there is no way to unregister any style*.

### Style or not Style

First, you must know that `VCL`'s styles uses internal `FRegisteredStyles` dictionary to store *all* registered styles. Style became registered after `TStyleManager.LoadFromFile(YourStyleName)` has been called. Unfortunately, style never gets removed from dictionary.

Do not use `UnregisterStyle` procedure. It doesn't unregister style at all. Simply removes specified style from the list of *available* styles. Thus, after you call `UnregisterStyle(YourStyle)` you just wipe out `YourStyle` from internal list, not from dictionary mentioned earlier and cannot set this style.

After successful call to `UnregisterStyle()` you may call `LoadFromFile()` method and wonder why applicaition said:

> Style 'Emerald' already registered.

This happens because `LoadFromFile()` method loads specified style and checks its existing in internal dictionary of registered styles. This checking always returns `true` as `UnregisterStyle()` procedure doesn't delete specified style from dictionary.

The same thing related also with property `StyleNames`. This property returns name of style uses internal `FRegisteredStyles` dictionary to obtain name of style with specified index.

If you want to know my opinion, such behaviour of style is weird. Method `UnregisterStyle()` should also delete specified style from dictionary. Maybe I am wrong but this is a real bug. On the other hand, there is no bug - you are trying to use undocumented method. The truth is somewhere near.

### Styled Result

As conclusion, I would recommend you to use direct access to styles to decide can you use the selected style or not. See the code below (assuming you have styling of application turned on):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(TStyleManager.Style['Emerald']) and TStyleManager.Style['Emerald'].Available then
    // Do your code
  else
    ShowMessage('Specified style is not available!');
end;
```

If you have sources of `VCL.Themes` you can easily check the plausibility of what I wrote here.

### High Technology

I have created `class-helper` for `TStyleManager` that allows to check if style-file registered and unregister it if needed. In order to fill `TStyleInfo` record with real values from style-file, we need save specified style to `TMemoryStream` and then pass stream to `IsValidStyle` function. Also we could use *physical path* to style (f.e. `C:\Embarcadero\Delphi\Styles\Emerald.vsf`) instead of variant with stream, but latter looks more elegant.

Unfortunately, according to *Remy's comment* (I don't know how to make a link to it), `C++ Builder` (which is used by OP) doesn't support `class-helper` feature. The only solution is to create simple unit which contains all code needed for `class-helper`. To work with it is enough to add such unit to `uses` clause and call appropriate public procedures\functions.

This unit have the following structure:

```
unit StyleManager_CH;

interface

uses
  VCL.Themes;


  function IsStyleRegistered_CH(var AStyle: TCustomStyleServices): Boolean;
  procedure UnregisterStyleEx_CH(var AStyle: TCustomStyleServices);


implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.Generics.Collections;


type
  TStyleManagerHelper = class helper for TStyleManager
  public
    class function IsStyleRegistered(var AStyle: TCustomStyleServices): Boolean;
    class procedure UnregisterStyleEx(var AStyle: TCustomStyleServices);
  end;


class function TStyleManagerHelper.IsStyleRegistered(var
  AStyle: TCustomStyleServices): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Assigned(AStyle) and
            TStyleManager.FRegisteredStyles.ContainsKey(AStyle.Name);
end;

class procedure TStyleManagerHelper.UnregisterStyleEx(var
  AStyle: TCustomStyleServices);
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  StyleInfo: TStyleInfo;
  SourceInfo: VCL.Themes.TStyleManager.TSourceInfo;
begin
  if Assigned(AStyle) then
    begin
      MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        AStyle.SaveToStream(MS);
        MS.Position := 0;
        if AStyle.IsValidStyle(MS, StyleInfo) then
          begin
            if TStyleManager.FRegisteredStyles.ContainsKey(StyleInfo.Name) then
              begin
                SourceInfo := TStyleManager.FRegisteredStyles.Items[StyleInfo.Name];
                if Assigned(SourceInfo.Data) then
                  FreeAndNil(SourceInfo.Data);

                TStyleManager.FStyles.Remove(AStyle);
                TStyleManager.FRegisteredStyles.Remove(StyleInfo.Name);
                FreeAndNil(AStyle);
              end;
          end;
      finally
        MS.Free;
      end;
    end;
end;

function IsStyleRegistered_CH(var AStyle: TCustomStyleServices): Boolean;
begin
  Result := TStyleManager.IsStyleRegistered(AStyle);
end;

procedure UnregisterStyleEx_CH(var AStyle: TCustomStyleServices);
begin
  TStyleManager.UnregisterStyleEx(AStyle);
end;


end.
```

Addendum `_CH` stands for `class-helper` abbreviation. There were also fixed some memory leaks.

I am not sure if there is another way to *reload* style-file "on-the-fly".

Comment: Actually UnregisterStyle is published (not private) and has an entry in the rad studio Help 

Comment: I edit a style file and i want to reload it from disk without rebuilding the application each time.

Comment: @Everybody_hates_BillTheLizard, yes I know. But what Embarcadero said about this metod: *Embarcadero Technologies does not currently have any additional information. Please help us document this topic by using the Discussion page!* It is less than nothing as for me)

Comment: @Everybody_hates_BillTheLizard, you don't need to rebuild your app each time you modified `*.vsf`-file. By the way how do you modified file?

Comment: Emba offers a tool. Bmp style editor is called. Or something like that. It is very basic.  It would be nice if they would release the code so i can improve it.

Comment: @Everybody_hates_BillTheLizard, yeah. I tested it right now and updated my answer. Check this. It works for me (tested it a bit).

Comment: @Dima the OP is using C++Builder, not Delphi. Even though C++Builder projects can use Delphi units, C++ does not support class helpers, that is a Delphi-only feature. But you could put this helper code into a standalone Delphi unit and have it expose some public non-helper functions that access `TStyleManager` as needed, and then use that unit in C++.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I never used C++ Builder and I thought it is similar to Delphi in most aspects. I changed my answer accordingly if I got your idea right.

Comment: @Dima you should move the class helper, and unit references other than `VCL.Themes`, into the `implementation` section. The `interface` only needs `VCL.Themes` and the 2 function declarations.